# not all toga modules have been installed due to an error during installation

Tags: python, runtime-error

when I tried to install *toga* with **pip install toga**, it installed but gave me an error:

```
  Installed:
    3 package(s) to packages.config projects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 292, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 272, in main
    python_h = preprocess_python_headers()
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 192, in preprocess_python_headers
    for line in _check_output(cmd).splitlines():
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 41, in _check_output
    output = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cfast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fep_tzdy\pythonnet\setup.py", line 405, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\cfast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fep_tzdy\pythonnet\setup.py", line 191, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, geninterop, interop_file])
  File "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\cfast\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\python.exe', 'tools\\geninterop\\geninterop.py', 'src\\runtime\

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\cfast\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cfast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-'\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cfast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-crjqtxre\install-record.txt --single-version-extell-fep_tzdy\pythonnet\
```

my python code:

```
import toga


class Freedom(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(self.name)
        self.main_window.app = self

        box = toga.Box()

        self.main_window.content = box
        self.main_window.show()


def main():
    return Freedom('Freedom Units', 'org.pybee.freedom')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when I run my code it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\apps\eclipse\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 19, in <module>    
main()
  File "c:\projects\apps\eclipse\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 16, in main
    return Freedom('Freedom Units', 'org.pybee.freedom')  File 
"C:\Users\cfast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\toga\app.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.factory = get_platform_factory(factory)  File 
"C:\Users\cfast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\toga\platform.py", line 42, in get_platform_factory
    from toga_winforms import factoryModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'toga_winforms'
```

then I tried to install toga_winforms with **pip install toga_Winforms**
but it gave me the same first error, I tried looking for solutions but got nowhere.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: This subprocces fails, try finding out why.. `Command '['c:\\users\\cfast\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\python.exe', 'tools\\geninterop\\geninterop.py', 'src\\runtime\`

Comment: how. can u at least give me some kind of instructions, that would be great ^^